# How do I get a file descriptor to null

Tags: c++, c

I have a program that performs certain tasks and logs the result to a file or to std out, however this causes a performance drop in the system. I would like to determine if the logging causes this problem.

I didn't write the program so I want to perform a nt very invasive analysis, logs log to either a file or stdout based on whether a file descriptor points to a file or contains the result of dup with stdout as the argument.

How do I point the file descriptor to nothing?

(I can't remove the call to logging itself)

Comment: `/dev/null`? you need to specify the OS.

Comment: Android, well linux I guess.

Comment: Basically directing it to /dev/null would still cause the app to log, only nobody would able to see it cause it doesn't get stored anywhere or go to stdout. correct?

Comment: I am not really sure, didn't think of that, can you modify the code? If the code does check for `fopen()` if it returns `NULL`, then just make the log file not readable for the user executing the program, then `fopen()` will return `NULL`, and the logging will not happen.

Comment: @iharob, many programs will throw an exception or crash if they can't open a log file, not just disable logging.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I said if the program handles not being able to `fopen()` the file.

Comment: Hook the call to your logging function to be a noop (simple return).